# Almacenar variable de JavaScript dentro de una variable PHP

Tags: php, javascript, funciones, variables, html-select

El siguiente problema corresponde a que cuando una persona seleccione un option de un select, se obtenga el value de esa option escogida y se guarde dentro de una variable php.

Aquí yo obtengo el Id de la option seleccionada.

**Se me ocurre por ejemplo utilizar done o success en js cuando se pase con exito la variable desde js a php dentro de la misma pagina, para ejecutar el código PHP de abajo** pero no se como quedaría.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#nivel-especialidad").change(function() {
  $("#nivel-especialidad option:selected").each(function ejecutar() {
    Id_nivel = $(this).val();
    $.post(Id_nivel);
    //OBTENER EL ID DE LA OPCION SELECCIONADA
    //ASIGNANDOLO A UNA VARIABLE PHP MAS ABAJO
      $("#requisitos-especialidad").load();
     // ESTE CODIGO PIENSO QUE IRIA DENTRO DEL SUCCESS O DONE DE JS
     // PARA PODER EJECUTAR EL CODIGO PHP DE ABAJO
     // QUE ESTA DENTRO DE UN DIV
    });
  })
});
</script>
```

El siguiente código PHP corresponde al que quiero ejecutar después de que el la variable PHP obtenga el ID_NIVEL:

```
<?php
$id_nivel = $_POST['Id_nivel'];
            //AQUI GUARDARIA EL VAR ID_NIVEL DE JS PARA PASARLO EN LA SIGUIENTE LINEA
    ?>

<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
    <div id="requisitos-nivel" name="requisitos-nivel">
    <?php
//ESTE ES EL CODIGO QUE QUIERO EJECUTAR DE FORMA DINAMICA CUANDO SE OBTENGA EL ID_NIVEL DENTRO DE LA VARIABLE PHP
$requisitos = DAORequisito :: consultarRequisitosPorIdNivel(Conexion :: obtenerConexion(), $id_nivel);//CONSULTA A LA BD

echo "<tr>";
for ($i = 0, $contador=1; $i < count($requisitos); $i++, $contador++) {?>
    <td>
    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
            <!--<img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">-->
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text"><?php
                echo $requisitos[$i] -> obtenerTexto();
                ?></p>
                <input type="checkbox">
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <?php if(($contador%3) == 0) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
?>
</div>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

No entendi mucho de lo que queres hacer pero...
Intentas obtener el valor de un select y el id de un usuario?

Deberias usar un `input:hidden` para enviar el id en el form, y en php usar `$_POST["id"]` y `$_POST["requisitos-nivel"]` para obtener el id y el valor seleccionado en el select

Comment: Gracias por responder, Si quiero obtener el valor del option que esta dentro del select-html, solamente sin Id de usuario. Mejore la redacción espero la puedas entender mejor ahora y me puedas aclarar el panorama.

Answer (score 0):

No queda muy claro la intención de lo que quieres hacer, pero tienes que tener en cuenta que Javascript se ejecuta del lado del cliente y PHP se ejecuta en el servidor. Teniendo esto presente debes utilizar el método HTTP POST  para realizar esta comunicación.

Para enviar los datos desde jQuery puedes utilizar `$.post();`

Chequea la doc [aquí](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Y para recibirlos en PHP  `$_POST[]` tal como indicó Ale arriba

La doc [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: Vale, gracias por responder, ahora he colocado el código como he entenido las respuestas, pero me aparece que en el post de PHP el index Id_nivel no esta definido.